# How do I randomly select 5% rows of each userid (column) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, random

How do I randomly select 5% rows of each userid column using MySQL?

That is, mytable contains userid column, and I want to randomly check each user's 5% of entered rows. So the  query should return 5% of each user's rows.

Comment: To the downvoters: Try yourself to answer the question. This is not as trivial as you apparently think it is.

Comment: @Jalpesh -----------i have done this using java..by passing parameters to the query...but this should be done by mysql quaries only..l have used  ORDER BY RAND() ..but this result not consist os 5% of each user..
if you know how to get that rows help it out

Comment: @jalpesh --and more over FYI...i have posted this query after all my attempts on this regard..

Comment: all downvoters will you please ans this question...i mean i think u have downvoted because it is little bit easy..so ans this question pls

Comment: +1 one to combat comment-less downvotes from another Thilo

Comment: I havent downvoted but i would guess that it is being downvoted because you have not shown any attempts to answer it yourself in the question.

Comment: @olly_uk not mean to any single one...but this is down voted soon after the question is posted....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution by using Events:

```
drop event OEAuditEvent;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT OEAuditEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
STARTS '2012-09-05 09:00:00'

DO
BEGIN

  DECLARE a CHAR(20);
  DECLARE b,c,d INT;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

  IF CURRENT_TIME() = '23:40:00' THEN
begin

 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select OE_User,count(OE_User) from RNCM_Status where     date(OE_Date)=CURDATE() group by OE_User;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 OPEN cur;
 read_loop: LOOP


 FETCH cur INTO a, b;

SET c=ceil((b*5)/100);

IF done THEN

          LEAVE read_loop;
ELSE
          insert into OE_Audit(MDN,CAF,UploadedDate,OEUser,OEDate,UserCount,QCCount,intime) select MDN,CAF,UploadedDate,OE_User,OE_Date,b,c,now() from RNCM_Status where OE_User=a and date(OE_Date)=CURDATE() order by rand() limit c;
    END IF;

 END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
 end ;
 END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can say:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

if you know there are 100 rows in the table.

If you don't know, you can try this query first to find out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

Otherwise, you can also try:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE RAND() < 0.05 ORDER BY RAND()
```

This selects approximately 5% of all rows (but it is a little random because it basically selects rows with 5% chance).

Otherwise, you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable)
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer the question. I am just hoping that there is a more efficient way to do this (such as Oracle's SAMPLE option)

Comment: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE RAND() <= 0.05 ORDER BY RAND() is working fine and returns 5% random of all rows...but that rows shold consist 0f 5% of each user...i.e iam asking about 5% rows of each user...is total table has 200 rows and user column of praveen has 10 rows,and sravani has 20 rows so on..result should cosist 2 rand rows of praveen, 4 rand rows of sravani and so on......

Comment: @Praveen Add a `where userID=(the users ID)` and it should limit it to just that of the user.

Comment: @Fluffeh  thats fine but is there is any way to retrieve all the users 5% data

Comment: @Praveen I did spend some time thinking about it, but short of a stored procedure or running two queries from your code, I couldn't think of a better solution than written here.